# List core audio devices

Tags: audio, mediaplayer

Using some old audio software that has buggy dialogs and I can't seem to be able to properly select my sound card. It just would stop responding when I click it.

I found the software has a configuration file and would accept a value like this:

`coreaudio://60 (Soundflower (64ch))`

It seems like the device id and some string value with the name of the device.

I would like to be able to list all available core audio devices on my MBP, so I can configure the application using this configuration file.

Would you help me, please? Some command line application or a media player that displays the core audio ids would do just fine.

Comment: Try running `grep key /Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist | grep :`

Comment: Just ran it, but it does not seem to show the id that I need. Example output: `<key>SoundflowerEngine:1</key>`. You can see the value is not `60` as in my example.